# gcc SO_DOMAIN does not compile with -std=c2x

Tags: c, linux, gcc, compiler-errors

Today I had revisited old code of mine. The code use `socket` and `getsockopt` calls. I had modified `makefile` to compile under `-std=c2x` to use modern `C`. Strangley enough the simple line of `getsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DOMAIN, &domain, &s_len)` did not compile.

The error is

> SO_DOMAIN undeclared

As per request, here is a minimal reproducible example. Note that, domain returns zero.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <sys/un.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 int sd = socket(AF_UNIX, SOCK_STREAM | SOCK_NONBLOCK, 0);
 int domain;
 socklen_t s_len; 

 if(sd < 0){
  perror("socket DID NOT create");
  return 1;
 }
 if(getsockopt(sd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_DOMAIN, &domain, &s_len) < 0){
  perror("getsockopt failed");
  return 2;
 }
 
 const char *so_domain = NULL;
 if(domain == AF_UNIX)
  so_domain = "AF_UNIX";

 printf("sock domain is: %d : %s\n", domain, so_domain);

 return 0;
}
```

The compile flags is `-D_POSIX_VERSION=200809L -D_XOPEN_VERSION=700 -D_XOPEN_UNIX=1`. But if the flags removed/added the error persists.

What can be the cause of this?

P.S I just did notice that including any `-std=` flags for `gcc` give this error. Even `c89` flags errors. My `gcc` version is

> gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04) 11.3.0

**UPDATE**

When I use the `-std=gnu2x` compiler switch it did find the define.

Comment: Please make it easier to people to reproduce this issue by providing a [mcve].

Comment: Note that `SO_DOMAIN` is not a POSIX-standard socket option.  It is not listed on [the POSIX `<sys/socket>` page](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/basedefs/sys_socket.h.html) nor in the [**2.10.16 Use of Options** section](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2018edition/functions/V2_chap02.html#tag_15_10_16).  It appears to be from `linux/socket.h` Linux kernel source, which on my RH8 system doesn't exist, but is mentioned in `bits/socket.h` in a comment. Nor does `SO_DOMAIN` exist in [this snapshot of glibc source code](https://github.com/bminor/glibc)

Comment: (cont) On my Ubuntu 20.04 system. `linux/socket.h` does exist and does define `SO_DOMAIN` but doesn't appear to be included unless `#include <linux/socket.h>` is *explicitly* added to source.  I suspect this is a dependency on Linux kernel headers and you've omitted that `#include`.

Comment: Is using `-std=gnu2x` an option?  It would be worth trying just to see whether `SO_DOMAIN` is defined then.  If it isn't, so be it.  If it is, you can start tracking down how to get it defined.  There will be a feature test macro that enables it.

Comment: @AndrewHenle `SO_DOMAIN` is listed in the Linux Mint 21.1 `man 7 socket`

Comment: @JonathanLeffler Thank you, the `-std=gnu2x` solved the issue. Silly me, I do not know how to track the define. The `gcc -E source.c | grep SO_DOMAIN` finds nothing.

Answer (score 1):

`-std=c2x` is not "the default but with C23 features."  That's because the default is one of the GNU C versions like `gnu17` (which year it uses depends on your GCC version).  You were effectively compiling with something like `-std=gnu17` before, not `-std=c17`.  Switching to `-std=c2x` did give you the C23 features, but took away (some of) the GNU extensions.

As Jonathan Leffler commented, the solution is to use `-std=gnu2x`, which keeps the GNU extensions you are relying on.

Comment: The code was used on FreeBSD. It has `SO_DOMAIN` with `-std=c2x` switch.

Comment: @user14063792468: I don't understand your comment.  The question title is "SO_DOMAIN does not compile with -std=c2x" but now you say "It has SO_DOMAIN with -std=c2x".  These seem contradictory.

Comment: I am compiling code on Linux, that I had used elsewhere(FreeBSD). The FreeBSD system compiles the code with the `-std=c2x` switch without issues. I think I have to add linux tag.

Comment: Ah, so SO_DOMAIN is usable on FreeBSD with `-std=c2x` but on Linux it requires `-std=gnu2x`.  Interesting.  Well, glad you got it sorted.